# how to find out table name after we combine some record from multiple table?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

okay i have source like this

```
public List<SearchRecord> getResult() {
        List<SearchRecord> searchResult = new ArrayList<SearchRecord>();
        String query = "SELECT " + A + ", " + B+ ", " + C
                + " FROM " + TABLE_A+ " UNION ALL SELECT " + A+ ", "
                + B+ ", " + C+ " FROM " + TABLE_B               + " UNION ALL SELECT " + A+ ", " + B+ ", "
                + C+ " FROM " + TABLE_C + " UNION ALL SELECT "
                + A+ ", " + B+ ", " + C+ " FROM "
                + TABLE_D;
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                SearchRecord sr = new SearchRecord();
                sr.setRecordA(cursor.getString(0));
                sr.setRecordB(cursor.getString(1));
                sr.setRecordC(cursor.getString(2));
                searchResult.add(sr);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            return searchResult;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

with this code i can get some record from multiple table who have same column name, and store the result in a List object. but how to i find out which table is this record belongs ? is it from TABLE_A, TABLE_B, TABLE_C, or the other

Comment: There is no way to know that. You can get it via indexes, because the columns of the result are built in order you stated them.

Comment: As an unrelated recommendation, I recommend you look at PreparedStatements, as they would clean up your code significantly.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per SQL, no, you are joining 3 sets of rows and operating them the same way, each record cannot be distinguished by its origin.

Of course, you could do something like

```
String query = "SELECT 'TABLE_A', " + A + ", " + B+ ", " + C
            + " FROM " + TABLE_A+ " UNION ALL SELECT 'TABLE_B' " + A+ ", "
            + B+ ", " + C+ " FROM " + TABLE_B 
            + " UNION ALL SELECT 'TABLE_C', " + A+ ", " + B+ ", "
            + C+ " FROM " + TABLE_C + " UNION ALL SELECT 'TABLE_D', "
            + A+ ", " + B+ ", " + C+ " FROM "
            + TABLE_D;
```

:-)

Comment: You'd also need to adjust your references where you're populating the SearchRecord - sr.setRecordA (cursor.getString(1))  - because getString (0) is the name of the table.

Comment: thank u Sjuan76 , it works .. :)) and yes you're right GregHNZ